# Excel Sum and Group By inplace?

Tags: excel, sum, excel-2007, vba

Basically I'd love to use a Pivote Table but it doesn't display correctly.

Say I have

```
    +---------+---+-----+
    |    A    | B |  C  |
  +-+---------+---+-----+
  |1|   Date  |Qty|Title|
  +-+---------+---+-----+
  |2|4/01/2013|10 |Foo  |
  +-+---------+---+-----+
  |3|4/01/2013|20 |Foo  |
  +-+---------+---+-----+
  |4|4/01/2013|5  |Bar  |
  +-+---------+---+-----+
  |5|4/01/2013|5  |Test1|
  +-+---------+---+-----+
  |6|4/01/2013|15 |Test2|
  +-+---------+---+-----+
```

I need to Achieve:

```
    +---------+---+-----+
    |    A    | B |  C  |
  +-+---------+---+-----+
  |1|   Date  |Qty|Title|
  +-+---------+---+-----+
  |2|4/01/2013|30 |Foo  |
  +-+---------+---+-----+
  |3|4/01/2013|5  |Bar  |
  +-+---------+---+-----+
  |4|4/01/2013|5  |Test1|
  +-+---------+---+-----+
  |5|4/01/2013|15 |Test2|
  +-+---------+---+-----+
```

The problem with Pivot Tables is that i can't seem to fix the fact that it wants to look like:

```
    +---------+---+-----+
    |    A    | B |  C  |
  +-+---------+---+-----+
  |1|   Date  |Qty|Title|
  +-+---------+---+-----+
  |2|4/01/2013|30 |Foo  |
  +-+---------+---+-----+
  |3|         |5  |Bar  |
  +-+---------+---+-----+
  |4|         |   |Test1|
  +-+---------+---+-----+
  |5|         |15 |Test2|
  +-+---------+---+-----+
```

And because this is being imported into a script, I have no control of, that uses each line for various reasons I need all lines to have all information.

Comment: Rather than VBA I'd use formulas next to my pivot table to repeat the data that is missing. So the formulas would be in columns D/E/F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this

```
    Sub Sum_And_Group()

    For Each Title In Range("C2:C20")
        If Title <> 0 Then
            Do While Title.Offset(1, 0) = Title
                Title.Offset(0, -1) = Title.Offset(0, -1) + Title.Offset(1, -1)
                Title.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
            Loop
        End If
    Next

    End Sub
```

And it works but seems a like unsafe and dirty. Anyone have anything better?

Answer (score 0):

There should be an option in the Pivot settings to `Repeat Item labels`

From Excel 2010 (I don't have 2007, can't be sure its in there too)

[image]

Comment: In 2007 that check box is not present.